# Create python app for mac

Tags: python, macos

I have built a python command prompt program that I would like to export so that when an icon is clicked, it will automatically run, much like an app, but I have never seen an app that runs in the terminal. Should I try to make it an app and if so, how is this done? (Specifically for Mac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about packaging your python script into a standalone application for Mac, you can use py2app

Link Here: https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/

You basically just write a python script, and then use this to help package it.

I hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a standalone app, just run a python script by clicking an icon, you can make a simple bash script to do it.

Here is a simple [tutorial](https://chimpy.wordpress.com/2010/08/29/mac-os-x-shortcut-link-to-python-script/) on that.

Comment: Is there a way to use this method allowing it to be used on other computers without entering the file path each time? I would like to distribute it.

Comment: Not really. If you want to distribute it, I recommend using @Xeno's answer. That will run everywhere, even if there's no python installed.

Answer (score 0):

If your script is small then the python docs indicate that the "Build Applet" tool might do the needful. See paragraph 4.5 of this [link](https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/mac.html).